# How to create JSON object in jquery by getting values through iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to JSON and jquery. I have the following use-case for which I need some help.

I need to create an array of objects in the following format:

```
{ "endpoint" : [ 
    { "ip": "16.140.23.90", "mac": "a2:35:67:e7" },
    { "ip": "16.140.23.91", "mac": "36:b1:79:ab" }
  ]
}
```

This is a sample of what I need (representing two rows only, there can be more). Now the value of ip and mac I need to add by iterating over a table's selected rows. 
E.g. there is a table on the GUI in which each row is having two columns "IP" and "MAC". I need to get the data of the selected rows in the above format.

How do I form the JSON array in the above format when I need to add the values of the attributes while iterating? Anything I can do using JSON.stringify API? If yes, then how do I form the string which I can pass to JSON.stringify which results in the above format?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your table (first cell is ip and 2nd cell is mac)

```
<table id='tbl'>
    <tr><td>16.140.23.90</td><td>a2:35:67:e7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>16.140.23.91</td><td>36:b1:79:ab</td></tr>
</table>
```

Pure JS

```
var ips = { "endpoint" : [] };
var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
for (var i=0; i<tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    ips["endpoint"].push({
        "ip" : tbl.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML,
        "mac" : tbl.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZV3CU/1/)

jQuery

```
var ips = { "endpoint" : [] };
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tbl tr').each(function(i) {
        ips["endpoint"].push({
            "ip" : $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
            "mac" : $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text()
        });
    });
    var json = (JSON.stringify(ips));
    document.getElementById('json').innerHTML = json;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZV3CU/1/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the prompt help! I am still in the learning process :)

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is good. But since this question is in regard to jquery, I provide a similar solution using jquery to manipulate the DOM. 
The table is still the same:

```
<table id='tbl'>
    <tr><td>16.140.23.90</td><td>a2:35:67:e7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>16.140.23.91</td><td>36:b1:79:ab</td></tr>
</table>
```

The javascript code to creat the json object:

```
var ips = { "endpoint": [] };
var rows = $('#tbl tr');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    ips["endpoint"].push({
        "ip": rows.eq(i).find("td").eq(0).text(),
        "mac": rows.eq(i).find("td").eq(1).text()
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/yLXmX/2/)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a serialized representation of javascript objects, so just make the objects in javascript and then serialize using the JSON.stringify method. If you're not sure how to make a javascript object and add values to an array, then you should do a little googling, since that's pretty basic stuff.